# Previous lines are cleared on ofstream

Tags: c++, ofstream

I would like to write a new line with a string on a file when the writeToFile function is called. Is that possible without clearing the previous line or the whole txt?

```
void writeToFile(string str) {
    ofstream fileToWrite;
    fileToWrite.open("C:/Users/Lucas/Documents/apps/resultado.txt");
    if(fileToWrite.good()) {
        //write the new line without clearing the txt
                //fileToWrite << str won't work for this reason
    }
    fileToWrite.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Look up `std::ios_base::ate` and `std::ios_base::app`.

```
void write_to_file(std::string const &str) { 
    std::ofstream fileToWrite("C:/Users/Lucas/Documents/apps/resultado.txt", 
                              std::ios_base::app);
    fileToWrite << str << "\n";
}
```

In this case, the difference between the two is irrelevant, but `ios_base::ate` means when you open the file, it's positioned at the end, so what you write is added to the end -- but if you want, you can seek to earlier parts of the file and overwrite what's there. With `ios_base::app`, before you do any write, it'll automatically seek to the end, so any writing you do gets appended to the end, rather than overwriting any existing data.